# .Net5, SAP & docker: UUID daemon (uuidd) is not active

Tags: docker, uuid, ubuntu-20.04, netweaver

I am trying to run a .Net 5 application in an docker container. This Application uses the [SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/nwrfcsdk.html) to connect to a SAP system. However it reports the error

> [UUID daemon (uuidd) is not active](https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2558132)

At first I tried to use the microsoft provided runtime image (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0) which produced the error initially.

Inital docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
# copy everything
Copy . .
WORKDIR "/src/SapClientService"
RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SapClientService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
ENV LD_DEBUG="all"
ENV LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT="/debug.txt"
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SapClientService.dll"]
```

I then tried to modify the runtime images by installing the runtime myself, so that I can install packages and so on.

```
ARG DOTNET_VERSION=5.0.8

FROM amd64/ubuntu:focal as runtime-deps

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        \
        # .NET Core dependencies
        libc6 \
        libgcc1 \
        libgssapi-krb5-2 \
        libicu66 \
        libssl1.1 \
        libstdc++6 \
        zlib1g \
        uuid \ # <- I added this
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV \
    # Configure web servers to bind to port 80 when present
    ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 \
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true

# Installer image
FROM amd64/buildpack-deps:focal-curl as runtime-installer
ARG DOTNET_VERSION

# Retrieve .NET
RUN curl -SL --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/$DOTNET_VERSION/dotnet-runtime-$DOTNET_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && dotnet_sha512='8789609f3039dca1d0dc19562f23bc9bfe5d513a2d10639a8a779afe7656447b7ee953f9a8d9d0b07ba6ca4a346770c0efb5a34e5240b5d355d4d8198220e9b1' \
    && echo "$dotnet_sha512  dotnet.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /dotnet \
    && tar -ozxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /dotnet \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz


# .NET runtime image
FROM runtime-deps as runtime
ARG DOTNET_VERSION

ENV DOTNET_VERSION=$DOTNET_VERSION

COPY --from=runtime-installer ["/dotnet", "/usr/share/dotnet"]

RUN ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
# copy everything
Copy . .
WORKDIR "/src/SapClientService"
RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SapClientService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
```

I used the content of the [ms-runtime-deps](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/c0e8be8a44b47b1dcc2a5b4b2ebd92022087ac0b/src/runtime-deps/3.1/focal/amd64/Dockerfile) and [ms-runtim](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/7b7cb07a09083dc16e5b17b869c326bba3add82d/src/runtime/5.0/focal/amd64/Dockerfile) dockerfiles as a base.

I tried installing the package `uuid` (which worked) but the `uuidd` still is not accesible.

So the central question would be where do I get this `uuidd` deamon from and how do I install/setup/start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what we need to do.

We need to install the packages `uuid` and `uuid-runtime`. And before we can start the `uuidd` we need to create the folder `/run/uuidd` by simply executing `mkdir /run/uuidd`.

At first I though I only need the package `uuid-runtime` and the folder `/run/uuidd` since I could start the deamon without a problem. But as soon the NetWeaver code wants a `uuid` the runtime totally crashes and I mean totally, it does not even output any errors.

So my `Dockerfile` looks now like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base

RUN mkdir /run/uuidd
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        # SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK dependencies
        \
        uuid \
        uuid-runtime \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
# copy everything
Copy . .
WORKDIR "/src/SapClientService"
RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SapClientService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "uuidd && exec dotnet SapClientService.dll" ]
```

and works well.

The last thing to not is the

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "uuidd && exec dotnet SapClientService.dll" ]
```

we have to start the `uuidd` manually and since docker seems to only want one start program we simply use `sh` to start `uuidd` and then our app. The `exec` however is important according to the [docker-docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example).